# Customizing SimpleCaptcha

Tags: captcha, simplecaptcha

We're using SimpleCaptcha http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/ to creating a captcha in our registration form (running on Tomcat)

We create the captcha using:

```
Captcha captcha = new Captcha.Builder(300, 57).build();
```

and the captcha is displayed as follows: 
[image]

But when I add more options to the captcha such as `Captcha captcha = new Captcha.Builder(300, 57).addNoise().build();`, it's still displayed in the same way without the noise. I tried more options but still get the same results.

Does anyone know why this is happening please?

Thanks,

Kurt

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code above (with java 1.6 version) and it produces nothing. The reason is that you don't have .addText(). (I would have written this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation for it). This suggests to me that your code above isn't your actual code, maybe you forgot something when posting.

Here's what I use that works:

```
public class MyCaptchaServlet extends SimpleCaptchaServlet
{
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Captcha captcha = new Captcha.Builder(120,40).addText().addBorder().gimp().addBackground(new GradiatedBackgroundProducer()).build();

        CaptchaServletUtil.writeImage(response, captcha.getImage());

        request.getSession().setAttribute(Captcha.NAME, captcha);
    }
}
```

Adding .addNoise() just before .build() does show the noise.